# Error in creating index in Mongo db using mongo console

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I am using this query for creating the index:

`db.CollectionName.createIndex({result: {$exists:true}, timestamp : {$gte: 1573890921898000}})`

What am I trying to do here is, creating indexing on timestamp > last month and for only those data where result exist, but I am getting error

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Values in v:2 index key pattern cannot be of type object. Only numbers > 0, numbers < 0, and strings are allowed.",
    "code" : 67,
    "codeName" : "CannotCreateIndex"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `createIndex` syntax must be followed as described in [this document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/index.html).

Comment: I think you are looking for [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/).

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @prasad_ for the suggestion, i needed to use partial_Indexes so the query becomes :

```
db.CollectionName.createIndex({result: 1, timestamp: 1}, {partialFilterExpression :{result: {$exists:true}, timestamp : {$gte: 1573890921898000}}})
```